# Why am I getting dependency-cycle reports when I add Rigid Body > Compound Parent?

Tags: python, physics

I have reduced the problem down to the Minimal (not ) Working Example. Here I have a cube mesh. I have eight smaller cubes (one at each corner of the larger cube). That’s it.

There are only three steps:

1/
I add Active Rigid Body to each of the small cubes. Collision Shape = ‘Box’. No Collision Margin.

2/
I parent the eight small cubes to the larger cube. The small cubes are the children. The larger cube is the parent. I used Parent (Keep Transform).

I usually do this all in Python but to isolate the problem, I have done steps one and two in the GUI.

3/
With the large cube **selected** and **active**, I use the following code to add the Collision Shape = ‘Compound Parent’ to the large cube.

I tried, script1.py

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.rigidbody.objects_add(type='ACTIVE')
bpy.ops.rigidbody.shape_change(type='COMPOUND')
```

I also tried, script2.py

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.rigidbody.objects_add(type='ACTIVE')
bpy.context.object.rigid_body.collision_shape = 'COMPOUND'
```

There are only two lines! But they throw up nine (not eight) “Dependency cycle detected” reports.
Why? What should I change?

Here is the simple Blend file BEFORE I run the Python code.
https://pasteall.org/blend/b0b4a0de72ab4a95820a441336d2abfd